# bash script create multiple directories within directories

Tags: bash

I want to create a directory structure like this in nix:

`mkdir -p 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` and within each of these folders I want folders `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`

I have started to write a simple loop like this (all the way up to folder 2) but this seems inefficient.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash   
for i in 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9; do mkdir -p 1/{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} $i, mkdir -p  2/{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} $2; done
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 6):

This should help (requires bash):

```
mkdir -p {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}/{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

Some newer versions of bash also allow this:

```
mkdir -p {1..9}/{1..9}
```

Comment: [3.0-alpha](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges#quoting_expansions_substitutions_and_related) from [2004](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html) introduced brace expansions.

Comment: Out of interest, how do I go one step further and add a,b,c,d under each folder. e.g. mkdir -p {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d}/{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d} with brace expansions?

Comment: @user1283693 Yes, it's just brace expansion, so this variant will work with any names, not only numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds simple enough unless I've misunderstood:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `seq 1 9`; do
  for j in `seq 1 9`; do
    mkdir -p $i/$j
  done
done
```

Comment: Oh, Michal's one-liner is cooler. I keep forgetting about bash's {} expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Perl Solution.

```
for($counter = 1; $counter <= 9; $counter++)
{
        `mkdir -p $counter/{1..9}`; //Executing Unix Command
}
```